# Which Star Trek character "wasn't him/herself" on the most occasions?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

This includes all occasions when,  at least temporarily, a character or the appearance of a character fooled, attempted to fool, or was intended to fool other characters or the audience.  The key point is v there has to be some notion of trickery or manipulation.

Clarifications:

- Multiple manipulations in the same episode count as one.

Counts:

- possession, external influence, mental illness
- simulations, hallucinations (by the perceiver)

Doesn't count:

- in-character lying
- in-universe acting

In the case of borderline or unclear cases,  please ask for clarification to I can improve the question.

Comment: Does it count when a character is replaced by their mirror universe alternate?

Comment: @user14111, yes,  that was an unfortunate typo, which wouldn't be ambiguous in any other universe :(

Comment: @Xantec, yes,  alternates fit the bill perfectly.

Comment: Re: sheer number I'd have to land w/ Data. As to length, there is a character in DS9 that is not himself for possibly years. Don't have time to cite these things however!

Comment: Harry Kim was replaced by his alternate universe double... and stayed that way for 5 more seasons...

Comment: To all, I'm going to refine this more,  with more examples.   Please stand by.

Comment: @Richard what are you referencing there?

Comment: @thomas - http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Deadlock_(episode)

Comment: So, although Data gets manipulated several times as different characters in 'Masks', because it's in the one episode it would only count as one, despite being different characters?

Comment: @N_Soong, yes,  that is one episode (groan) of not being himself.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we follow the question (as stated), where there's an actual *intent to deceive* then the winner seems to be TNG with **Picard** coming in at 8 times, closely followed by Data with 7 times.

[image]

Other series don't seem to come anywhere near (Ent/Tucker = 3, DS9/Dax = 3, Voy/Chakotay = 4)

Comment: Some of these may not count for Picard - the question may need more narrowing. I.E. - re: Gambit. Picard is Picard for the viewing audience - in-universe he is simply undercover (which the question precludes as 'acting/lying'). Rascals would not technically count either since he is still fully Picard, just physically younger. Even Time Squared may not count because there are two Picards.

Comment: @NKCampbell - In Rascals he pretends to be Riker's son, tricking the Ferengi intruders. In Time Squared there aren't two Picards. Only one of them is the real one, the other is...erm...not.

Comment: @NKCampbell - "or was intended to fool other characters" is a bit vague. Riker gets dressed up as a local in [First Contact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Contact_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)).

Comment: yeah @Richard - seems like the question needs some clarification. I read it as mainly seeking to identify outside influences taking over a person, not somebody going undercover or deliberate deception of an enemy (Gambit /Rascals) since it says" Doesn't count: in-character lying | in-universe acting)

Comment: @Richard, this is along the right lines,  but I don't intend for it to be restricted to "deceptive takeovers".   I'm going for apparent representations of the character which are not the bona fide original person or original personality.   For example,  I'd  take "Remember Me"  and  "Frame of Mind" representations too.  Does that help?

Comment: @NKCampbell, yes,  that is what I meant.   Character is either under the influence or isn't the character at all,  even though they appear to be.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - In that case the question is deeply flawed.

Comment: @Richard, on what basis?    It's  flawed because you interpreted it a different way?   I'm seeking help to refine it.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - It's deeply flawed because it can be interpreted in multiple ways, all correct/wrong.

Comment: Wouldn't both parts of "Best of Both Worlds" count as well? Picard wasn't really being himself either in those episodes.

Comment: @cbredlow - There was no intent to deceive though.

Comment: @Richard "•possession, external influence, mental illness*" I'd count the Borg assimilation as an external influence.

Comment: @cbredlow - True, but the Borg don't pretend that he still Picard. They openly rename him.